# Run 4 individual form submit functions from a single button click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, submit

I am currently attempting to make a page that would allow for users to search multiple knowledge bases from a single field.

Currently, I have been able to build this tool out so that clicking the corresponding button will search the designated tool, but I am trying to get a single button to search all 4.

Where I am stuck is the function tied to the All button.  When I click it, it only appears to be running the last function in the group rather than opening 4 browser tabs with all 4 results.

I have attached a JSFiddle, in case my explanation is poor.

Note: The page is not pretty as I am trying to get it working before I add any CSS.  I really just need JS advice.  I am still somewhat of a novice with JS, so if anyone can provide a fairly simple solution, that would be most ideal.

Super Search Fiddle:

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/paplad123/bpncvL1o/#&togetherjs=R5LO6yencG](https://jsfiddle.net/paplad123/bpncvL1o/#&togetherjs=R5LO6yencG)

Comment: One question : In the doAll(), if one of the searches fail, should it stop the search and return the value or should go for the next one?

Comment: It should go to the next.  Basically, I wish for it to display any search results, even if they are blank.

Comment: To be fair, the links in there are generic, so 3 of them won't work, but that is just because the real links are internal to the business.

Comment: Then you might want to remove the `return retvalue` after every search. Because, lets say GoogleSearch() fails, then it just exits the function without doing any other search.

Comment: I see.  Do you recommend an alternative?  Again, my JS is novice at best, so I often find things that work that aren't really proper or recommended.  I state this as I do not wish to come off as pushing back, but rather as someone seeking understanding.  including the return retvalue was the closest to the correct result I have gotten.  With the way things are currently, if I hit the All button 4 times, it will open all 4 searches.  On the 5th time I hit it, it reloads all 4 tabs but with the new search criteria.

Comment: When it comes to a google search, is it possible to make a search that would actually "fail", or would the search engine still display a page?  What could reduce the 4 clicks to 1?

Comment: Hmmm I dont know if you can do a google search that will fail. Well I have given a solution(idea sort of) that might satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to give an idea on how it might work depending on you needs. Ill assume that all the searches return a boolean value. So the code would go something like this:

```
function doAll() {
  var msg = ["google","payroll","inquira","sdfc"]
  var retvalue = [googleSearch(),payrollSearch(),inquiraSearch(),sfdcSearch()];
  for (var i = 0; i < retvalue.length; i++){
    if(retvalue[i] == false){
      console.log(msg[i]+" search returned false");
    }
  }
}
```

It will do all the searches first and after it finishes, it will give out which searches failed, but you can change that functionality according to your needs.

Hope it helps

Update/Alternative(Almost same code):

```
function doAll() {
  var msg = ["google","payroll","inquira","sdfc"]
  var retvalue1 = googleSearch();
  var retvalue2 = payrollSearch();
  var retvalue3 = inquiraSearch();
  var retvalue4 = sfdcSearch();
  var retvalue = [retvalue1,retvalue2,retvalue3,retvalue4];
  //var retvalue = [googleSearch(),payrollSearch(),inquiraSearch(),sfdcSearch()];
  for (var i = 0; i < retvalue.length; i++){
    if(retvalue[i] == false){
      console.log(msg[i]+" search returned false");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user5842323 If it helps you and you were able to find a way to solve the problem, then kindly accept the answer or mark it as useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am afraid that did not work.

Comment: So what happened now??

Comment: I am actually getting a lesser result.  When I click **All**, only one page opens like before; however, subsequent clicks of the same button just result in new instances of the same search.  The 3 other search functions that come before that search function never run....or appear not to.

Comment: How about you try this and see if it works, instead of making it as a `retvalue` array, for each search declare a new retvalue like : `var retvalue1 = googleSearch()` and `var retvalue2 = payrollSearch()` and so on. Ill update the answer, check it out and see if that works.

Comment: So, if I already have the target tabs open, this works like a charm; however, if I am starting fresh and none of the target tabs are open, it only opens the window tied to the last function.

Comment: Your advice has given me an avenue to look into though.  While it hasn't solved for this issue, it has helped in giving me new paths to study.  I am going to see if there is a way to load the target windows first, such as with an onLoad on the body.  If that works, I may be able to make the rest work.

Comment: Well I can give a suggestion, if you are able to open a target tab first(let it be blank) and then do the operations and load the content into that..... I think it would solve your problem

Comment: Well, that let's me know I have the right idea, as that is what I was thinking.  Again, I appreciate your help.  It is my first time reaching out through the forums, and this has proven fruitful.  I have upvoted your help.

Comment: @user5842323 You are welcome, so this answer can be marked as helpful.